# Get User From Usermanger After Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to get a user from the usermanger after External Login, using .Net-Core and IdentityServer4

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        var serviceProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PublicAstootContext>();
        var coinbaseRule = new CoinbaseRule();
        await coinbaseRule.UpdateCoinbaseAccountInfo(context, user.Id, info);    
        //...
    }
}
```

However, even after the login succeeds, when I attempt to get the user from the usermanger, the user is always null.

How can I get the user from the usermanger after my external login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` does not populate `HttpContext.User` - it ends up writing an authentication cookie that is read in *subsequent* requests when attempting to populate `HttpContext.User`, but not before. In your example, the call to `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` occurs within the *same request* as the call to `GetUserAsync`, which means that `HttpContext.User` will not represent an authenticated user and so no match will be found.

Instead, you can use [`UserManager.FindByLoginAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyloginasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to get the correct value for `user`:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(
    info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
```